# Discord.py - Command not found using cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently having some issues in regards to a command not being recognised using cogs within discord.py, I managed to get the cog up and running properly about 20 minutes ago before all of a sudden it's suddenly stopped being recognised as a command and my error handler I implemented isn't helping out very much only telling me what I already know (being that the command isn't recognised). Here is the specific error message my handler is giving me:

[image: Handler Error]

and here is my main application file

```py
# Imports
from datetime import datetime
import json, discord, datetime, logging, os
from colorama import Fore
from discord.ext import commands

from commands.basic import basic

# Load json config from file
with open('data/bot/config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    token = data["TOKEN"]
    prefix = data["PREFIX"]

# Store time and date as a variable (Hour_Minute_Day_Month_Year)
timeinfo = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y')

# Save Discord Intents as variable
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

# Define bot user
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

# Define log handler as variable
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='data/logs/data_' + str(timeinfo) + '.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')

# Bot startup
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{Fore.MAGENTA}[{Fore.RESET}!{Fore.MAGENTA}]{Fore.RESET} Successfully logged in as {bot.user}') # State in console when bot is initialised

# Add Basic command category
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(basic(bot))

# Run Bot
bot.run(token, log_handler=handler)
```

and this is the cog I am trying to implement from which no commands are being recognised:

```py
# Imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Define Cog class
class basic(commands.Cog, name="Basic Commands"): 
    def __init__(self, bot, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bot = bot 
    
# Commands
    async def mimic(ctx, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)

# Define Setup
def setup(bot): 
    bot.add_cog(basic(bot))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

In main you should be using `load_extension` instead of add_cog.

```py
bot.load_extension('your_cog_file_name')
```

For your cog, setup is correctly implemented, but you should also take `self` as an argument for the command:

```py
async def mimic(self, ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Reference for [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)

Comment: I appreciate the correction on my syntax however after implementing both of these changes the "mimic" command is still not being recognised, I'll have a little tinker around. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Load the extension inside `on_ready`, it should work properly. You can also try to debug with vscode and check where your code is failing to find the command.

Comment: Loaded the extension under on_ready to no avail :( Been spending the past 2 hours trying to find a solution but no luck yet, stupid thing was I had it working beforehand and somehow broke it yet it's not in my VS code timeline due to it being too long ago. Going to continue trying to debug, wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Using @Pedro Cribé answer:**
This code may help you:

```
#main.py
import asyncio
#...
async def load():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
async def main():
  await load()
  await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Also, i think you dont need the `*args` and `**kwargs` values in `class basic.init`:

```
#cogs.basic
class basic(commands.Cog, name="Basic Commands"):
  """A description, if you want"""
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def mimic(self, ctx, arg):
    await ctx.reply(arg)

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(basic(bot))
```

If you are using any dpy branch like Pycord you need to remove all `async/await` expressions except for command and events, but, if you are using dpy you **mustn't** remove them:

```
#with pycord or other branch
#cogs
def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(cog(bot))

#main.py
import os

def load():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
      bot.load_extencion(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Importing respective packages